# Why does salesforce use a subdomain for logging in?

Tags: login

To log into salesforce without a custom domain set up we go to "login.salesforce.com" What benefits, if any, are gained by using a subdomain for logging in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce used to have a login page at https://www.salesforce.com/login, actually. You can use it today, but you'll simply be redirected to https://login.salesforce.com/. This enhancement allows for better scalability, security, and other enhancements that simply were not possible by using the main www site. There was a brief period before this server was introduced where customers would start to have problems logging in, mostly because of page timeouts.

Architecturally, it also makes it easier to perform maintenance and upgrades. Any significantly large web application benefits from using subdomains, load balancing, caches, etc, and Salesforce is no exception. The main thing you need to take away from this is that having a sub-domain allows for more reliable, faster logins than sharing authentication with the main www server.

Answer (score 2):

If it is using a subdomain then it will be a different server which you can redirect users to. As per my understanding, using login.salesforce.com will let Salesforce hold the login process on a different server and from here, users can be redirected to their respective instances. 
Typically, login.salesforce.com is used to make the login process distinct from the rest of the Salesforce platform. It is being used for the shared authentication process for many Salesforce services.

Keeping it separate allows other instances to go through the maintenance without affecting the login process. If www.salesforce.com/login was being used for the login process then it will be stored on the same server in a subdirectory and which will not make it a separate service.

***On a separate note about subdomains/custom domain in Salesforce org***

Basically, it lets you enhanced your login security by defining your custom login policies and Single Sign-On in your org.

From the documentation -

> - Customize the login page with your own branding.
> - Use Identity features for single sign-on.
> - My Domain is required to:
>     Enable users to single sign-on into a Salesforce org
>     Use a Salesforce    org as an identity provider for
>     single sign-on into third-party    applications or other Salesforce
>     orgs.
> - Preserve deep links (such as    https://yourDomain.my.salesforce.com//001/o) through any future org splits and migrations.

Reference to docs - 
[What are the advantages of My Domain?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_domain_name_advantages.htm&type=5)

Comment: My question was about not about using a custom branded domain or the benefits of it. I am wanting to know why do they use "login.salesforce.com" instead of something like "salesforce.com/login".  I understand the benefits of the "My Domain" feature @naval-sharma